# How can I use module exports with existing libraries?

Tags: node.js, module

For example, I have `posts.js` with a function that adds post data to an SQLite DB, so I need to require the `sqlite` library in that file.

But if I have another filed called `comments.js` with a function that adds comment data, I need to require the `sqlite` library in that file again.

That's how I'm doing it at the moment, and the only way I can figure out how to get it to work. Is there a better way to do this? For example require the `sqlite` library in the main file, and be able to use it in `posts.js` and `comments.js`?

Answer (score 0):

There is not wrong with the way you do it. It is how people use `require`.

You will not be able to use it if you require `sqlite` in the main file, because your other files with throw `undefined` error for missing `sqlite` in them.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up your `sqlite` connection in your `main.js` like so:

```
global.db = require('sqlite');
```

And then it will be available in all of your other files

Answer (score 0):

There's no way since before a module's code is executed, Node.js will wrap it with a function wrapper to keep top-level variables scoped to the module rather than the global object.

However, you can set it in a global variable: `global.sqlite = require('sqlite');` but you shouldn't do this to avoid typing 'require'.

You should try using some design pattern like dependency injection.